# HTTP GET request works in Postman or with cURL in a Command Prompt, but not when making the same request in .NET Core

Tags: c#, http, curl, https

When requesting this document, http://www.newsen.com/, through Postman or cURL I'll get a response in less than a second, but when I make the same HTTP GET request with C# I never get a response and the Task eventually cancels.

My code:

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "http://www.newsen.com/");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); // Will throw an exception after about 1 minute of doing nothing.
```

Typing `curl http://www.newsen.com/` in a Command Prompt retrieves the document just fine, same when sending a GET request using Postman.

After further testing I've noticed that when you specify the default proxy in the cURL command: `curl -x http://localhost:8888 -k http://www.newsen.com/` also gets stuck and eventually times out. So it has something to do with that proxy, which also gets used when making a request in C#. I just don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Can you post the code that's calling this code?

Comment: @devNull I don't understand your question.

Comment: Where is the code that you posted being called from (e.g. a console application, a web service)? Wherever that is, can you include the call site in your question?

Comment: @devNull the code is executed on my local machine from within Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Right, but what kind of project is the code in?

Comment: @devNull Console Application (.NET Core 3.0)

Comment: Okay cool. So there's an entry point in a console application, usually defined as `static void Main()`. And you're probably calling the code that you've posted somewhere within that `Main` method. Can you include all of that code in your question?

Comment: @devNull Sure, but it's the same as the code that is in my question ```using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing2
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "http://www.newsen.com/");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I was just curious if the Task was being blocked further up the chain, since that can cause deadlocks with similar results to what you're seeing. But the code that you have works, it even runs successfully [in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PHwEbf). That at least confirms that the code is fine, there's just likely something specific to your environment that is causing the issue

Comment: @devNull I've had other people try to check this for me, they experienced the same issue, works with cURL or Postman, doesn't work in C# or Python. Could you try running this code locally on your own machine? As well as I said in my question, I can get a response from the host, I just can't get a response when I request it with C#.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and your code works just fine for me. Does the exception being thrown include any useful information?

Comment: Nope, it just throws a TaskCancelledException after a minute or two.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `TaskCancelledException` is due to the call timing out, but I could be wrong. I'm not sure what is making it timeout though; the URL works for me with cURL and in a browser, but the code fails for me as well.